# How to pass output of a PTransform as side input?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use output of a transform as a side-input to the next one. But I see that the side-input is empty. Can anyone help me figuring out the issue?

My original code is a bit complex, but this is an example.

```py
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import pvalue

class transfrom(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
        yield pvalue.TaggedOutput("example",tuple(element.items()))

class Test(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
        


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    read = (
            p | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query="""{}""".format(query_input_table),use_standard_sql=True)))

    trans = (read | 'transform' >> beam.Pardo(transform()).with_outputs())

    ((read | 'transform' >> beam.Pardo(Test(),pvalue.AsDict(trans))))
```

Comment: I was not able to execute the code syntax. There was no side input, but a branching pipeline code instead. Could you elaborate more on your process? How do you ingest your side input and how do you want to incorporate it to your main input?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your `transfrom` DoFn does not need to output elements on a specific tag. You'll be fine doing the following:

```py
class transfrom(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
        yield tuple(element.items())
```

And to pass the element as a side input:

```py
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    read = (
            p | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query="""{}""".format(query_input_table),use_standard_sql=True)))

    trans = (read | 'transform' >> beam.Pardo(transform()))

    ((read | 'transform' >> beam.Pardo(Test(),pvalue.AsDict(trans))))
```

Now, just to be sure: Is the code in `transfrom` correct? You should be returning tuples with two elements, so that the dictionary can be built. Is that what `tuple(element.items())` returns?